# How do I inline a div in navbar element

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I am having some problems with my html. I am making a navbar offcanvas. Here is my code:

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <a class="navbar-brand mx-2" href="#">Olau Pla Richart</a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="offcanvas" data-bs-target="#offcanvasDarkNavbar" aria-controls="offcanvasDarkNavbar">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="offcanvas offcanvas-end text-bg-dark" tabindex="-1" id="offcanvasDarkNavbar" aria-labelledby="offcanvasDarkNavbarLabel">
            <div class="offcanvas-header">
              <h4 class="offcanvas-title" id="offcanvasDarkNavbarLabel">Menu</h4>
              <button type="button" class="btn-close btn-close-white" data-bs-dismiss="offcanvas" aria-label="Close"></button>
            </div>
            <div class="offcanvas-body">
              <ul class="navbar-nav justify-content-end flex-grow-1 pe-3">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <h5><a class="nav-link active border-bottom bi bi-house" href="#home"> Home</a></h5>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <h5><a class="nav-link border-bottom bi bi-info-circle" href="#about"> About</a></h5>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <h5><a class="nav-link border-bottom bi bi-person-lines-fill" href="#contact"> Contact</a></h5>
                  </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <h5><a class="nav-link border-bottom bi bi-card-heading" href="#"> Blog</a></h5>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <a>Test</a>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

What I am trying to do is get the `Test` in the same line as `Olau Pla Richart`. Here is what my code does at the moment:

[image]

I tried adding `display: inline;` and `display: inline-block;` but I got no change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move your `div`, also wrap `a` and that same `div` (now `span`) in a `div` to not get spaced because bootstrap 5 has this rule `.navbar > .container-fluid { ... , justify-content: space-between}`

```css
.test {
  color: white
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-gH2yIJqKdNHPEq0n4Mqa/HGKIhSkIHeL5AyhkYV8i59U5AR6csBvApHHNl/vI1Bx" crossorigin="anonymous">

<nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div>
      <a class="navbar-brand mx-2" href="#">Olau Pla Richart</a>
      <span>
       <a class="test" href="#">Test</a>
      </span>
    </div>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="offcanvas" data-bs-target="#offcanvasDarkNavbar" aria-controls="offcanvasDarkNavbar">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="offcanvas offcanvas-end text-bg-dark" tabindex="-1" id="offcanvasDarkNavbar" aria-labelledby="offcanvasDarkNavbarLabel">
      <div class="offcanvas-header">
        <h4 class="offcanvas-title" id="offcanvasDarkNavbarLabel">Menu</h4>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close btn-close-white" data-bs-dismiss="offcanvas" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="offcanvas-body">
        <ul class="navbar-nav justify-content-end flex-grow-1 pe-3">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <h5><a class="nav-link active border-bottom bi bi-house" href="#home"> Home</a></h5>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <h5><a class="nav-link border-bottom bi bi-info-circle" href="#about"> About</a></h5>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <h5><a class="nav-link border-bottom bi bi-person-lines-fill" href="#contact"> Contact</a></h5>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <h5><a class="nav-link border-bottom bi bi-card-heading" href="#"> Blog</a></h5>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try border-bottom (border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc)
[details](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_border.asp)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `display: flex;` to your navbar class.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need any additional CSS, You just need to place the `a` in the the proper place (after `.navbar-brand`), and add `.navbar-text` to get the correct color for `.navbar-dark`/`.navbar-light`. It will be centered between `.navbar-brand` and `.navbar-toggler` by default. You can use `.me-auto` to left-align it, or `.ms-auto` to right-align.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-gH2yIJqKdNHPEq0n4Mqa/HGKIhSkIHeL5AyhkYV8i59U5AR6csBvApHHNl/vI1Bx" crossorigin="anonymous">

<nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand mx-2" href="#">Olau Pla Richart</a>
    <a class="navbar-text ms-auto me-2">Test</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="offcanvas" data-bs-target="#offcanvasDarkNavbar" aria-controls="offcanvasDarkNavbar">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
    <div class="offcanvas offcanvas-end text-bg-dark" tabindex="-1" id="offcanvasDarkNavbar" aria-labelledby="offcanvasDarkNavbarLabel">
      <div class="offcanvas-header">
        <h4 class="offcanvas-title" id="offcanvasDarkNavbarLabel">Menu</h4>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close btn-close-white" data-bs-dismiss="offcanvas" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="offcanvas-body">
        <ul class="navbar-nav justify-content-end flex-grow-1 pe-3">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <h5><a class="nav-link active border-bottom bi bi-house" href="#home"> Home</a></h5>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <h5><a class="nav-link border-bottom bi bi-info-circle" href="#about"> About</a></h5>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <h5><a class="nav-link border-bottom bi bi-person-lines-fill" href="#contact"> Contact</a></h5>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <h5><a class="nav-link border-bottom bi bi-card-heading" href="#"> Blog</a></h5>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

</nav>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-A3rJD856KowSb7dwlZdYEkO39Gagi7vIsF0jrRAoQmDKKtQBHUuLZ9AsSv4jD4Xa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```